# Null Values in Left Outer Join Table

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I have this situation in Oracle while trying to do a select from 2 tables:

## Table1

```
-------------
Col1   Col2
-------------
1      abc
2      aa
3      lab
4      mm
5      nn 
6      kk 
7      pp
```

## Table 2

```
-----------
Col1   Col2
----------
  4    xxx

  7    yyy

(null) zzz
```

I want all rows including (null) zzz of Table2 in my select.
What I am doing is -

```
SELECT column1, column2,….FROM Table1, Table2 Where table1.col1 = Table2.col1(+)
```

But it does not give me the row with NULL value in Table2.

I tried putting OR conditions with left outer join on col1 but it does not work.

```
SELECT column1, column2,…. FROM Table1, Table2 Where table1.col1 = Table2.col1(+) OR Table2.Col1 IS NULL
```

This is expected output:

```
    Col1 Table1.Col2 Table2.Col2
--------------------------------    
      1      abc     (null)
      
      2      aa      (null)
      
      3      lab     (null)
      
      4      mm       xxx
      
      5      nn      (null)
      
      6      kk      (null)
      
      7      pp       yyy
      
(null)      (null)    zzz
```

Comment: What is the output you're expecting to see? Also, if there was a row with col1 = 8 in your table 2, would you expect to see that row in the output?

Comment: You didn't answer what you wanted to see if table2 had a row with col1 = 8; do you expect see that row in the output with a null table1.col1? If so, Kaushik's answer of a full outer join is what you need). If not, then Kaushik's answer plus an additional filter on `table1.col1 is null and table2.col1 is not null` should suffice.

Comment: @Boneist - Thanks for your reply. your question about having a row with col1 = 8 in table2 - 'This is not possible scenario for my case'. And, for using FULL OUTER JOIN, I can use, but I have multiple other tables which are being joined on different other conditions with these. So, If I want to use explicit notation of joins instead of (+) notation, would I need to change all joins in the query ?

Comment: Please clarify via editing your question, not comments. Also, although the example is helpful, please always clearly explain how output is a function of input. PS Don't use (+). Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. But anyway you don't understand how (+) works, read the documentation. If an alias appears both with & without (+) then the (+) is ignored. Use subqueries when necessary. Learn what full join on returns: left join on union right join on.

Answer (score 2):

Its seems what you want is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aed61/13)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    t1.COl1
    ,t1.col2
    ,t2.col2
FROM Table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON
         ( t1.col1 = t2.col1 ) 
     ORDER BY Col1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aed61/13/0)**:

```
|   COL1 |   COL2 |   COL2 |
|--------|--------|--------|
|      1 |    abc | (null) |
|      2 |     aa | (null) |
|      3 |    lab | (null) |
|      4 |     mm |    xxx |
|      5 |     nn | (null) |
|      6 |     kk | (null) |
|      7 |     pp |    yyy |
| (null) | (null) |    zzz |
```

An **important** advice to you is to get rid of `(+)` outer join notation and use ANSI `.. JOIN ON` syntax.